# Alt+Scroll speed up for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, scrolling

In Firefox I have grown rather dependent on the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+*Mouse-scroll-wheel*. 
It makes the number of lines scrolled with mouse to be at a much higher factor.

E.g.: `about:config`

```
mousewheel.with_alt.delta_multiplier_y = 600
```

I'd say in 85% of my scrolling the *speed-up* is used. Scrolling with normal speed seems like running under water. But, of course sometimes it is what one want/need.

And, yes, I also use PageUp/Down, etc. but that is beside the point.

---

Question: Is there some similar functionality for Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I did not manage to find this one, but it surely solves the issue.

[Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb)

Answer (score 1):

I have made this for myself and for everyone who need it :)
Download my Chrome extension "Smart Mouse Wheel" :)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smart-mouse-wheel/hmbkakhgciflffmdngolckcoabhjkcen?hl=ru
Now mouse wheel+Alt wheel scroll 3 times faster, how  I like :)